# What is the difference between available expressions analysis and very busy expressions analysis?

Tags: static-analysis

I am having trouble understanding the conceptual meaning of the two kinds of analysis. I know the equations and how to solve the problems and I know how one is a forward data-flow analysis while the other is a backwards data-flow analysis, but there is still something missing in the explanations I have seen so far, in a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the Gen for these Analyses.

Gen(VBE) :

gen VBE ([x = e ;] l ) = AExp(e)

gen VBE ([while (b)  …  ] l ) = AExp(b)

gen VBE ([if (b)  …  ] l ) = AExp(b)

gen VBE ([…  ] l ) = ∅

Gen(AE) :

gen AE ([x = e ;] l ) = {a’ ∈ AExp(e) | x not in vars(a’  ) }

gen AE ([while (b)  …  ] l ) = AExp(b)

gen AE ([if (b)  …  ] l ) = AExp(b)

gen AE ([…  ] l ) = ∅

Thus, for a statement:
**x = x + y**

**x + y** is generated for VBE but not for AE.